# Insert into select con columna autonumerica

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo una migración masiva de datos entre esquemas de la misma base de datos de SQL Server. En dichos esquemas tengo una tabla con diseño idéntico en ambos esquemas pero con una columna autonumérica.

Por ello al hacer la siguiente query me da error:

```
insert into ESQUEMA1.TABLA1 
select * from ESQUEMA2.TABLA1
```

Se podría solucionar listando todas las columnas menos las autonuméricas pero tengo que hacer esto en un montón de tablas y es imposible

¿Alguna solución?

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que da? ¿Las dos tablas son idénticas realmente? ¿Te interesa copiar en la nueva tabla el valor del auto-increment o generar uno nuevo (ten en cuenta que en la tabla vieja puede haber saltos en el auto-increment)? ¿La tabla se va a relacionar con otras **ya existentes** en base al auto-increment? Son todas situaciones delicadas que debes tener claras, porque pueden provocar situaciones inesperadas en tus datos.

Comment: No es posible, si tienes un `identity` en la tabla de destino deberás especificar todos los campos que quieres insertar. Puedes montarte una función que lea en `sys.columns` y te devuelva la lista de campos, componer la sentencia del insert como un varchar junto a los campos de la función y hacer un `EXEC` para la inserción de datos efectiva.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Cual es la idea atras de esto? porque usualmente se usan las columnas autonumericas como FK en otras tablas, y si haces esto, es muy probable que muchas FK se rompan.

Comment: @A. Cedano Me interesa generar un nuevo autoincrement. Las tablas tienen otra PK diferente así que los valores que existen del autoincrement no son necesarios

Comment: @gbianchi Ya se que generalmente es así pero en este caso las relaciones entre tablas estan hechas por otros campos por lo que no hay ningún problema en machacar los valores autonumericos que tiene la tabla de origen

Comment: He encontrado esta solución y aunque no es lo que mas me gusta parece que funciona
-- Select everything into temp table
Select * Into 
    #tmpBigTable
    From [YourBigTable]

-- Drop the Primary Key Column from the temp table  
Alter Table #tmpBigTable Drop Column [PrimaryKeyColumn]

-- Insert that into your other big table
Insert Into [YourOtherBigTable]
    Select * From #tmpBigTable

-- Drop the temp table you created
Drop Table #tmpBigTable

Comment: O sea, por no escribir los campos usas una tabla temporal? y si mejor escribis un proceso que escriba los select por vos ;)

Comment: Si no te molesta conservar los `identity` originales puedes hacer uso del `SET SET IDENTITY_INSERT ESQUEMA1.TABLA1 ON;` antes de hacer el insert.

Comment: Hola burlok. Me parece tardaste más haciendo esta pregunta que lo que hubieses tardado en escribir las columnas en la query.

Answer (score -1):

Puede insertar los datos de la siguiente manera, conservando los valor del auto-increment de la tabla origen

1. Se debe Inactivar la opción de identity de la tabla donde van a ser insertados los datos. Según imagen. Para ello click derecho en la tabla, diseño, cambiar a NO, luego Guardar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Ejecuta tu script
3. Activa nuevamente el identity en la tabla donde inserto los datos,cambiandolo a SI, luego Guardar

Y listo consulta las dos tablas el cual deben tener exactamente los mismos datos